# Replacing a variable for an expression in a theano graph

Tags: python, theano

Given the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

x,y,z = T.dmatrices('x','y','z')
A = theano.shared(np.random.rand(3,4), borrow=True, name='A')
B = theano.shared(np.random.rand(3,4), borrow=True, name='B')

f = x+y+B
```

Is it possible to replace *y* by *z+A* in the expression *f*, so it becomes equivalent to *x+z+A+B*?. It could be done manually, by searching the graph for occurrences of *y* and replacing them by *z+A*. However, it seems logical to have a simpler high-level way to do it in the API.

Answer (score 1):

This has been [discussed on the theano-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/xjjwOXGioh4).

You can use either the `givens` mechanism of `theano.function` or use `theano.clone`.

Here's some example code:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

x, y, z = T.dmatrices('x', 'y', 'z')
A = theano.shared(np.random.rand(3, 4), borrow=True, name='A')
B = theano.shared(np.random.rand(3, 4), borrow=True, name='B')

h1 = x + y + B
h2 = theano.clone(h1, {y: z + A})

f1 = theano.function([x, y], h1)
f2 = theano.function([x, z], h2)
f3 = theano.function([x, z], h1, givens={y: z + A})

a = np.random.randn(3, 4)
b = np.random.randn(3, 4)
print f1(a, b)
print f2(a, b)
print f3(a, b)
```

Note that the inputs to the theano functions have to be adjusted to ensure only the unspecified tensors are accepted as inputs (i.e. `y` is no longer an input once it is replaced by a function of `z`).